# create matplotlib subplot for different dataframes and new figure for each column of the dataframes

Tags: pandas, loops, matplotlib, subplot, enumerate

I have a dataset that is comprised of daily PM2.5/PM10 ratios over a 7 year time period for 28 different sites. I have created four new dataframes that separates the dataset into each season of the year. All dataframes are structured the same and have the same column names. I want to write a code that makes **four subplots** with histograms **for each season at each site**, so I would have 28 total figures, each with four subplots. I am having trouble writing a loop that can alternate between the dataframes but keep the column the same. I am preparing histograms because I want to look at the distribution of PM2.5/PM10 ratios for each season at each site.

So far I have tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


pmf_spr = pd.read_csv('***/PM25PM10ratio_spring_IVAN.csv')
pmf_sum = pd.read_csv('***/PM25PM10ratio_summer_IVAN.csv')
pmf_fall = pd.read_csv('***/PM25PM10ratio_fall_IVAN.csv')
pmf_win = pd.read_csv('***/PM25PM10ratio_winter_IVAN.csv')


exps = [pmf_spr, pmf_sum, pmf_fall, pmf_win]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols=2, figsize = (12,12))

for i, col in enumerate(exps.columns):
    sns.histplot(data=col, color='green', ax=axs[i, 0])
    sns.histplot(data=col, color='orange', ax=axs[i, 1])
    sns.histplot(data=col, color='purple', ax=axs[i, 2])
    sns.histplot(data=col, color='blue', ax=axs[i, 3])
```

but I get an error message that says `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'`.

I understand why I got this error message and I also understand that the code I have written in the histplot() cannot specify between seasons but I am unsure how to improve the code. I also tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

pmf_spr = '***/PM25PM10ratio_spring_IVAN.csv'
pmf_sum = '***/PM25PM10ratio_summer_IVAN.csv'
pmf_fall = '***/PM25PM10ratio_fall_IVAN.csv'
pmf_win = '***/PM25PM10ratio_winter_IVAN.csv'

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols=2, figsize = (12,12))
for i,col in range(len(pmf_spr.columns)): 
    sns.histplot(data=pmf_spr.columns, color='green', ax=axs[i, 0])
    sns.histplot(data=pmf_sum.columns, color='orange', ax=axs[i, 1])
    sns.histplot(data=pmf_fall.columns, color='purple', ax=axs[i, 2])
    sns.histplot(data=pmf_win.columns, color='blue', ax=axs[i, 3])
```

but it also does not work, due to some sort of error in the for loop. I would appreciate help in making the 28 figures based on the column name with four subplots for each season.

Here is the sample data:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1weoPc5hCQqg05io6-D14Nca17oZaL68x?usp=sharing

**note that the date is the index for these files.

Comment: you're not calling `pd.read_csv` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

here's an approach that creates one large `df` out of the 4 separate seasons df's which makes plotting easier. Also decided lineplots looked nicer and colored the background of the plots by season.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import seaborn as sns

exps = [pmf_spr, pmf_sum, pmf_fall, pmf_win]

#I see you already have a column called 'Season', so we can create one big table
#by stacking the four tables on top of each other
df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(p, parse_dates=['Date']) for p in exps)


#Convert to "long_form" so the table looks like:
#   Season  Date    Month   Location    Value
#0  Spring  2017-03-01  3   1201 West Hwy 98    -1.562254
#1  Spring  2017-03-02  3   1201 West Hwy 98    2.172422
#2  Spring  2017-03-03  3   1201 West Hwy 98    0.826644
long_df = df.melt(
    id_vars=['Season','Date','Month'],
    var_name='Location', 
    value_name='Value',
).fillna(0) #not sure how you want to handle null values

long_df['Year'] = long_df['Date'].dt.year

season_colors = {
    'Summer':'yellow',
    'Fall':'orange',
    'Winter':'blue',
    'Spring':'green',
}

legend_labels = season_colors.keys()
legend_markers = [Line2D([0], [0], color=c, lw=4) for c in season_colors.values()]


#plot each location individually with a separate plot for each season
for location,site_df in long_df.groupby('Location'):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,1))
    sns.lineplot(
        x = 'Date',
        y = 'Value',
        color = 'black',
        data = site_df,
    )
    
    season_boundaries = site_df.groupby(['Season','Year'])['Date'].agg(['min','max'])
    for season,color in season_colors.items():
        for i,r in season_boundaries.loc[season].iterrows():
            plt.axvspan(r['min'], r['max'], alpha=0.2, color=color)
    
    plt.title(location)
    plt.legend(legend_markers,legend_labels,bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
    plt.xlim(long_df['Date'].min(),long_df['Date'].max())
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this doesn't really help me. I am preparing histograms because I want to see the distribution of PM2.5/PM10 ratios for the 7 years of data that I have and want to show the differences of the distributions between seasons, which is why I need them to be four separate plots on the same figure.